# Why the result of this program is three decimal numbers "597, 295, 295," for input of two hexadecimal numbers "255 127<enter>"

Tags: c++, stringstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream> using namespace std;

void printer(int i) {
    cout << setw(4) << i << ", "; }

int main() {
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    stringstream input(s); //LINE I
    vector<int> v1;
    int i;
    do {
        input >> hex >> i;
        v1.push_back(i); //LINE II
    } while (!input.fail());
    for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), printer);
    return 0; }
```

Similarly this program outputs `t,  r,  e,  e,` for file content `t r e`. I believe the reason is very similar to above question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void printer(char c) {
        cout << setw(2) << c << ", ";
}
int main ()
{
        ifstream inputfile("input.txt");
        vector<char> v1;
        char c;
        do 
        {
                inputfile>>c;//LINE I
                v1.push_back(c);
        } 
        while (inputfile.good());//LINE II
        inputfile.close();
        for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), printer);
        return 0;
}
```

**These are questions from an assessment. I need to understand the *why*. Of course, knowing the correction would improve my skills too. But I need to explain why it does not work that way.**

Comment: You need to check `good` / `fail` *before* doing `push_back`

Comment: Ok, but why? These are assessment questions. I just need to understand the why. I am not expected to correct the program, though it probably helps to understand better.

Comment: Why do you have to check whether you got new data before you add it to a collection? Because if you don't, the last time in the loop when you don't get new data, you'll add the old data again.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't get it. It should consume the last letter *e*. Then it should consume nothing, right? Or do you mean that `c` is not assigned a value and keeps the last `char`?

Comment: @Elyasin Whatever value `c` has, you call `push_back` again when you shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

You first try to read, then push the result to vector, than check if an error occured. That order is wrong.

```
while (true) {
    input >> hex >> i;
    if (input.fail())
        break;
    v1.push_back(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
do 
{
        inputfile>>c;//LINE I
        v1.push_back(c);
} 
while (inputfile.good());//LINE II
```

with

```
input >> hex >> i;
while (!input.fail()) {
    v1.push_back(i); //LINE II
    input >> hex >> i;
}
```

Note the second version is also correct if your input is empty. First check your input then insert it into vector.